# I can't get AngularJS to load my services

Tags: angularjs

I'm writing this to get help with an issue that I am having with AngularJS. This is a reoccuring issue in my coding education since no matter what, my biggest problems in coding were always how to link the files together. In AngularJS it has been unnerving for me because I have been trying for months to get my code to work and I cannot even link it on a basic level, so writing further code is useless.

I will post my HTML and all my AngularJS files for you to see and please tell me what it is I am doing wrong, and how to prevent this for the future. I'm doing a codecademy fullstack course and I will be needing to add ReactJS and Jquery as well. I go the Jquery transitions to work on all other parts of my site, but I fear it will be a problem once I try to put it here.

P.s. I don't know how to make multiple Javascript files in JSfiddle, but I hope it'll do.

The code:

```
var app = angular.module("SugesstionBox", []);

// my HomeController.js file

app.controller("HomeController", ['$scope', 'suggestions' function($scope, suggestions){
    $scope.posts = suggestions.posts;
   $scope.message = "AngularJS Tutorial";
}]);

// My suggestions.js service file

app.factory('suggestions', [function(){
    var demosuggestions = {
        posts: [
            {
            title: 'free pizza is amazing!',
            upvotes: 1,
            comments: [],
            },
            {

            title: 'free pizza is still amazing!',
            upvotes: 5,
            comments: [],
            }

        ]

    };
    return demosuggestions;
}]);
```

[Complete example on JSFiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/salimfarhat/9znr99ku/)

Comment: you had missed a comma in controller definition. Here's your working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9znr99ku/1/

Comment: Oh thank you thank you! I knew it had to be something small, but I didn't see it. It works now. I hope to be able to finally move on. I've wasted so much time as a result of dumb mistakes like that. I could have been employable by now!

Comment: glad that helped :)

Answer (score 0):

check this

https://jsfiddle.net/durga598/9znr99ku/2/

in html setting tab put `<body ng-app="SugesstionBox">`
and in javascript tab `LOAD TYPE:-No-wrap in <body>`

Answer (score 0):

AS tanmay said you missed the proper declaration and in your fiddle your calling your scripts which are not available in fiddle.....
More over i suggest you to use ng -if for comments do show better view like below and it is `post.upvotes` not `post.upvote`

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller("HomeController", ['$scope', 'suggestions', function($scope, suggestions){
    $scope.posts = suggestions.posts;
   $scope.message = "AngularJS Tutorial";
}]);
app.factory('suggestions', [function(){
    var demosuggestions = {
        posts: [
            {
            title: 'free pizza is amazing!',
            upvotes: 1,
            comments: [],
            },
            {
                
            title: 'free pizza is still amazing!',
            upvotes: 5,
            comments: [],
            }
            
        ]
        
    };
    return demosuggestions;
}]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.12/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="HomeController">
    <div>
            {{ message }}
        </div>
        <div ng-repeat="post in posts">
        <div>
        {{post.title}}</div>
        <div>
        {{post.upvotes}}</div>
        <div ng-if="post.comments.length>0">
        {{post.comments}}</div>
        </div>
  </body>

</html>
```